# Re-parse escaped subfields from json data in logstash

Tags: logstash

I want try parse json data in logstash. but it's nested and escaped.

I have question about re-parse escaped json in subfields in json.

For example:

```
{"d1": 1, "d2": "{\"c1\": 1, \"c2\": 2}" }
```

In generally programming environments, that is so easy for solve this problem.

but, logstash configuaration is not easily approach for this case.

Can I get hint for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

```
filter {

    # this parses the first json
    json {
        source => "message"
    }

    # This parses your nested json
    json {
        source => "d2"
    }

}
```

You can just set the source to whatever your field with raw escaped json  is. The filter does everything else for you.

With stdin/stdout and your input, you get:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf2/
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
{"d1": 1, "d2": "{\"c1\": 1, \"c2\": 2}" }
{
       "message" => "{\"d1\": 1, \"d2\": \"{\\\"c1\\\": 1, \\\"c2\\\": 2}\" }",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-08-08T11:49:19.381Z",
          "host" => "pandaadb",
            "d1" => 1,
            "d2" => "{\"c1\": 1, \"c2\": 2}",
            "c1" => 1,
            "c2" => 2
}
```

EDIT:

If the "d2" raw property bothers you, you can remove that field after you parse it.

Cheers,

Artur